# Happy Marriage Anniversary or Congratulations of Marriage Anniversary?

Tags: word-usage, american-english, phrase-usage

Today mine best friend has Marriage Anniversary. I wished "Happy Marriage Anniversary". I am confused whether I spoke the right words. May be I should have congratulated. Can anybody help me here with correct usage?

Comment: In the UK, I would say that 'wedding anniversaries', as we call them, are celebrated between the marriage partners. They are not like birthdays when  everyone's friends get involved. Just 'happy anniversary' would do. Unless it's a silver, gold or diamond anniversary when there is something considerable to celebrate.

Comment: Thanks @NigelJ. I was just thinking, we should say **Congratulations** when somebody had got/received something. And **Happy....** when we want to wish for something good. Am I right?

Comment: Strictly speaking yes, this is why **congratulations** is more formal. But it is implied that you are wishing them a happy annyiversary anyway. Both are correct.

Comment: @KamalSingh Yes, 'congratulations' is a good response.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between "wedding" and "marriage"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172131/difference-between-wedding-and-marriage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with "Happy Marriage Anniversary". It is more common to say, "wedding anniversary" however, or just "happy anniversary" which implies "wedding", especially that the people concerned know it.

There are online e-cards even with "Happy Marriage Anniversary" wording:
https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Happy+Marriage+Anniversary%22&tbm=isch

As to "Congratulations": it sounds more formal, which depends on you if you would want to say it to a friend. Both are correct.